# How to define an empty list of string in jshell in a shortest possible way?

Tags: java, jshell

I want to create an empty list of type `List<String>` in `jshell`

I am hoping `jshell` supports some sort of syntax shorthand for example:

```
  List<String> args = []
```

However it failed with this error message:

```
|  Error:
|  illegal start of expression
|  List<String> args = [];
|                      ^
```

Of course I can just use the standard java expression:

```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList
List<String> args = ImmutableList.of()
```

but I want to know if it can be more terse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're initialising a `List` you can do it as:

```
List<String> list = List.of();
```

If instead it was an array, you could have initialized it as :

```
String[] arr = {}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about var keyword this comes with java 10:

```
var list = new ArrayList<String>(); // infers ArrayList<String>
```